# Derive a theoretical bound about coding with a partial eavesdropper

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, it.information-theory

This post is improved from [Determine binary function $f(x)$ by partial observation of $x$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280737/). Since the form of the problem is changed in a great extent. I would like to create a new post rather than edit the old one. If it is inappropriate, feel free to edit these two.

---

Let us start with some random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ and $Y$. Suppose Alice wants to transmit $Y$ to Bob by using $n$ communication channels. She does this by directly sending $X_i$ through the $i$-th channel respectively. Of course, the fact that this coding is correct gives us
$$
H(Y|X_1,\dots,X_n)=0
$$
Now, here is an eavesdropper Eve. She can observe random $k$ channels out of $n$. In other words, she will know random $k$ variables out of $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Suppose the coding scheme can guarantee that Eve will not gain too more information about $Y$, by
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}} \sum_{\substack{A \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} \\ |A|=k}} I(Y; (X_i : i \in A)) \leq \epsilon
$$
Then we can derive a bound about $\sum_{i=1}^n H(X_i)$:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n H(X_i) \geq \frac{1}{(n-k)\binom{n}{k}} \sum_{\substack{A \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} \\ |A|=k}} H((X_i:i \notin A)) \\
\geq \frac{1}{(n-k)\binom{n}{k}}  \sum_{\substack{A \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} \\ |A|=k}} I(Y;(X_i:i \notin A) | (X_i:i \in A)) \\
= \frac{1}{(n-k)\binom{n}{k}}  \sum_{\substack{A \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} \\ |A|=k}} 
\left( I(Y;X_1,\dots,X_n) - I(Y;(X_i:i \in A)) \right) \\
=\frac{1}{n-k}(H(Y)-\epsilon)
$$
My question:

> Is this bound tight or asymptotic optimal? Is there any reference related to this problem, since it seems to be quite natural?

---

**Trivial result.** For $k = n-1$ and $\epsilon=0$, the bound is tight. For a construction one can refer to [here](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/280737/).

**Result from Xitip**. I have used [Xitip](http://xitip.epfl.ch/) to verify the inequality where $n \leq 5$. I found that when I slightly increase the coefficient ($1/(n-k)$), the program reported that it would be no longer a Shannon-type inequality. This fact suggests that if the bound is not tight, we *may* find a family of new non-Shannon-type inequalities.

---

Cross-posted at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/39102/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(comment) If all subsets of size k leak $\frac{\epsilon}{n}$ bits, then you are looking at threshold (secret-sharing) schemes. In that specific case, it is tight: the bound is the *threshold gap* and the construction is a ramp scheme. Your leak condition being quite loose, other structures usually require a different bound (possibly with non-Shannon-type inequalities).

Comment: Could you please give some references with regard to the threshold secret-sharing schemes when all subsets leak the same information?

Comment: @Lwins.Gafield: maybe http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/14/ajc-v14-p51.pdf can help. Alos, Example 2.9 in https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/124.pdf

Comment: I noticed that the Example 2.9 in your paper (thanks!) is not a general scheme for arbitrary secret $Y$. I mean, could it be generated to a universal scheme such that it can reach the threshold for any certain $Y$?

Comment: tl;dr: No, not in general.
If $Y$ is not uniformly distributed, little is known. You can replace Y by typical values of $M$ i.i.d. copies to make it quasi-uniform and the result should still hold. Otherwise, if dealing with general $Y$, our paper shows a general construction which is exponential in $n$, how to improve these scheme is a major open question.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation. Whereas here is something making me confused. By using your method, it seems that we could not guarantee $H(Y) = H(M)$. As an example, would you be so kind to show that how to deal with $Y$ when it is uniformly distributed on $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: For basics, you should start by learning about Shamir's scheme, then modify it to get a ramp scheme (what you want). As for binary random variables, I think you need at least as many values as the number of variables for a ramp scheme. A new result proves you need at least log n values (but this is state-of-the-art stuff)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean when referring to "$\log n$" values. Is it consistent with $n$ in the OP? Or you mean that when $Y$ is binary, the bound will be not tight?

Comment: Yes, the same $n$, but this is specific to ramp schemes. In general, it is not known. Do you have a construction for any $\epsilon$ and (uniform) binary $Y$ ?

Comment: No, this is why I asked this question here. Well, there is something unclear to me still. Did you mean that if we want to reach the bound (by ramp scheme), $Y$ should have at least $\log n$, or $n$ possible values? If so, it implies that we have not found a threshold scheme for secret $Y$ when $Y$ is (uniform) binary. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't clear. You would need log(n) bits, more details can be found in https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2016/131/download/

Comment: After reading Bogdanov et al.'s paper I have come up with a new question making me confused. They prove that the share size should be $\Omega(\log n)$. But it seems _not_ to imply that $H(X_i) \geq \Omega(\log n)$. Would you like to give me a direction on this?